# Что больше, 10^10 или long long?

Tags: c++

Возможно ли число 10<sup>10</sup> засунуть в `long long` или не влезет?

Comment: Так попробуйте запихнуть.

Comment: Нет возможности

Comment: 10^10 = 10000000000, 2^64 = 18446744073709551616, в случае именно long long - делим результат на 2, получаем 9223372036854775807

Comment: Нет компилятора под рукой? Так есть онлайн компиляторы.

Comment: Тут даже компилятор под рукой не надо, достаточно калькулятор достать...

Comment: @test123 Ну может человек не знает, сколько бит в лонг лонге.

Comment: Короче, в знаковый long long влезет число порядка 10^19. Так понятнее?

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Влезет, с огромным запасом.

Вот, почитайте: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

В `long long` гарантированно влезают числа от -9,223,372,036,854,775,807 до 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (т.е. ±(2<sup>64-1</sup>-1) )

На абсолютном большинстве систем нижняя граница на один ниже: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

Компилятору разрешается иметь `long long` еще большего размера, но в жизни я такого не видел.

Comment: *"на большинстве"* — есть хотя бы один современный пример не "two's complement" c++ платформы?

Comment: @jfs Поэтому у меня написано просто "на большинстве систем" а не "на большинстве современных систем". :)

Comment: @jfs А вообще, вот нагуглил пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440337/2752075.

Comment: я не вижу что по ссылке должен был увидеть. Слово "современный" можно убрать. Знаете хоть один пример для C++ (не C), где не "two's complement" реализация?

Comment: @jfs Пытаетесь доказать, что их нет вообще? Если хорошенько покопаться в гугле, то наверняка можно найти какую-нибудь древность. Или взять Unisys ClearPath, который упоминается по ссылке. Он из коробки поддерживает С. Берете Comeau C/C++ compiler, который умеет транслировать С++ в С (или вообще cfront), и вот вам С++ на one's complement.

Comment: это просто вопрос: могли бы честно ответить: "я не знаю примеров с++ реализаций, которые не используют two's complement"

Comment: @jfs Имеете в виду, что это такая редкость, что без гугла не назвать? С этим я не спорю.

Comment: Я не вижу примера для C++ по ссылке. Ещё раз Си и C++  это разные языки.

Comment: @jfs Поэтому я упомянул Comeau.

Comment: Думаю, все тут в курсе уже, но для полноты: в C++20 уже не бывает не не "two's complement" реализации, соотвесвующей стандарту.

Answer (score 5):

У типа `long long` нет заранее фиксированного диапазона, однако спецификация языка требует, чтобы он был не уже чем [-(2<sup>63</sup> - 1), 2<sup>63</sup> - 1]. Поэтому значение 10<sup>10</sup> в него влезет.

Comment: Уделал вас на 7 секунд. :Р

Comment: OK :) Зато у меня показатели степени филигранно суперскриптом выписаны :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Это у вас неправильный. :) Стандарт разрешает хранить числа не только в two's complement, но и в one's complement (по-русски - не только в дополнительном, но в в обратном коде). Так что нижняя граница взята большая из двух, т.е. для one's complement. Пруф по ссылке у меня в ответе.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov: Диапазон скопирован прямо из стандарта. Что же в нем неправильного?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: И дело не только в этом. Даже при использовании дополнительного кода реализациям разрешается резервировать значение `-2^63` в качестве trap representation. Поэтому формально представимость `-2^63` - не гарантируется даже в дополнительном коде.

Comment: Интересно, мне в голову не приходило.

Answer (score 2):

в любых случаях для встроенных типов просто проверьте или утвердите:

```
assert(numeric_limits<long long>::max() > x);
assert(numeric_limits<long long>::min() < x);
if (numeric_limits<long long>::max() > x ||  numeric_limits<long long>::min() < x))
cout << "ok";
```

Answer (score 1):

Размер `long long` - 8 байт. 8 байт = 2<sup>64</sup> бит. 10<sup>10</sup> = 10000000000. Значение переменной типа `long long` может быть -2<sup>63</sup> *<= x <* 2<sup>63</sup>. Число 2<sup>63</sup> очевидно больше, чем число 10000000000, следовательно, переменной типа `long long` можно присвоить значение 10<sup>10</sup>. ***Ответ: да.***

Comment: Придирка: 8 байт *минимум*.

Answer (score 1):

Тип `long long` хранит 64 битные целые числа. Поскольку старший бит используется для обозначения знака, то остаются 63 бита. Т.е. в тип `long long` можно записать любое число из диапазона [−2<sup>63</sup> + 1 … 2<sup>63</sup> − 1]

Очевидно, что число 10<sup>10</sup> больше нуля. Попробуем сравнить его с 2<sup>63</sup>

10<sup>10</sup> < 16<sup>10</sup> = (2<sup>4</sup>)<sup>10</sup> = 2<sup>40</sup> < 2<sup>63</sup>

Comment: Даже при использовании дополнительного кода реализациям разрешается резервировать значение `-2^63` в качестве trap representation. Поэтому представимость `-2^63` - не гарантируется. Гарантированный нижний край - `-(2^63 - 1)`.

Comment: @AnT. Действительно. Исправил